# Guzzle ServerException resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response

Tags: php, laravel-5, microservices, guzzle, lumen

I'm trying to implement a MicroService Architecture Using Lumen and laravel

I'm using laravel 5.4 as an ApiGetway and using Lumen 5.4 as a microService

the thing here i'm using GuzzleHTTP version 6.3 in my laravel project, trying to hit the microService API, but i'm getting 500 Internal Server Error

I'm trying this in my localhost

This is how i'm making requests:

```
public function get_posts(){
    try {

       $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
       $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/micro/posts_micro_service/public/posts');
         if($res->getStatusCode() == "200"){
             echo $res->getBody();
         }else{
             return response()->json(['status',"error"]);
         }
     } catch (ClientException $e) {
            echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
            echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
 (1/1) ServerException
Server error: `GET http://localhost/micro/posts_micro_service/public/posts` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<style>
(truncated...)
in RequestException.php (line 113)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run php server using a new port 
 Eg:-

For Laravel:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

For Lumen:

```
php -S localhost:8001 -t public
```

It worked for me. Use this method rather than setting vhost.

Comment: nice, already fine for me

Answer (score -1):

The problem was because Lumen and Laravel are using the same Machine and Sharing the same environment so when i did a call the environment variables they were overrides.

Comment: So what was the solution you came up with